# using 2 ajax calls in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I want to make a ajax function to post data that I've loaded using another ajax function. I already discovered to use a callback function, but how do I pass data from the one function to the other. I've tried this :

```
getData(function{
 $.ajax({
  do stuff...,
  data: dataArray,
  do stuff...
 )}
});

function getData(callback){
 $.ajax({
  do stuff...,
  data: dataArray,
  do stuff...,
  success: function(data){
   dataArray = fill array with stuff;
   callback();
  }
 )}
};
```

looks like the array isn't available to the callback function...

Is this the solution I should think of, or is there another way to wait for the first ajax call to finish?

gr

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are doing, but you have syntax errors so this code won't even compile.

Comment: Try writing a reduced test case that demonstrates your problem. Try to avoid using global variables or reusing variable names.

Comment: No, this code doesn't compile, it is to demonstrate how my flow is built.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code seems so complicated so I am writing a new one. You can make your own by looking at my code.

Try this;

```
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: 'http://geturl.com',
success: postdata(dataToPost)});

function postdata(dataToPost){
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url: 'http://posturl.com',
data: datatoPost
});
```

Comment: If you add in the missing characters so that this compiles, that won't work. `success` needs to be a function, not the `undefined` return value of a function.